# Delete multiple rows from table with frequent reads and writes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have a table that has frequent reads, inserts & updates (it holds website users' session data).  It has a clustered index on a `varchar` field called `sessionID`.

I need to delete a bunch of records based on a list of `sessionID`s in another table. When I try to delete a large amount of them at a time, a lock is created that prevents the table from being written to and read from.

If I delete them row by row using a foreach loop in an SSIS package, it seems to eliminate the locking.

Are there any possible long-term negative effects to deleting row by row?

Comment: With the method that you say works, does it negate the lock? if so you might get dirty data from reading data that hasn't yet been committed. This of course depends on how you delete the data.

Comment: Not sure, but this might let your log file grow pretty fast. I think you do not need to delete by row, better figure out a chunk size where the lock does not hurt the other activities and [delete in chunks](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes).

Comment: thanks @DrCopyPaste, that's a helpful link.  I did run a test to delete 5000 records row by row and the transaction log did not increase at all. (simple recovery model)  We currently delete in chunks of 5000 at a time which is creating locks.

Comment: for this scenario one can consider using logical deletion

Comment: You could alse delete in smaller trunks, like 100 of 250 rows at a time. Mostly the will be faster as one by one and the table will be locked much shorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this is a question about tab locks, page locks, and row locks. Whats happening is you are deleting from multiple pages so sql locks the whole table. Sql generally uses a single lock per transactions, so it will choose the smallest lock that covers all rows affected. Delete a single row and it will use a rowlock, delete several sequential records and it can use a page lock, delete records from across multiple pages and it will lock the whole table.

With a varchar as a PK and clustered index you unlikely to ever hit a page lock, because the order that records appear in the table is random (more on why that's highly undesirable in a minute). So your choices are row locks or tab locks, since locking the table isn't an option, row locks are your only choice.

As for bad effects, well there is the transaction log issue mentioned by drcopypaste, but there is a much worse issue if your PK/clustered is not sequential. If it's not sequential every time you insert a record or delete a record, the DB has to move all of the subsequent records, because a clustered index (which is almost always on the table pk) is how the rows are physically sorted on the table.

Comment: thanks, so it sounds like row by row is the only option but ideally we want to create a different table that has an identity as the primary key and then an index on the sessionID?

Comment: Depends if your PK (the varchar) is sequential, if it is then it's not too big a deal (it makes indexes huge and slows down any reads but not too bad), if it isn't then you could add an identity column to the table, switch the clustered and pk to that, and reduce the disk IO required for changes to that table by an order of magnitude or more.